# Tracking user's behaviour

Tags: expresso-store, tracking

I have a site which has audio files to listen to and optionally download. Restrictions to accessing the file is to become a site member. Is it possible to track that the member has listened (clicked) to the file? This site has Devdemons Store installed, which perhaps could provide a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ExpressionEngine you could use something like Channel Files, which if you use obfuscated links runs it through ExpressionEngine and documents the download in the database. http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-files

Otherwise you could use JS event tracking.  Google event tracking documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Parscale, I did look at Channel Files and Link Vault. How do I access the obfuscated links stats - can this be added to the members account? or integrated with STORE? Pity CF still has it's own - unlinked with EE - categories. (confusing for the client)

Comment: In Channel Files there is a single database table with all of this. In about 2 minutes you could use exp:query to display the download stats per member in a front-end template. If you buy just make an stack exchange question if you need help.

Comment: Parscale is totally right :)
I used Google event tracking and it is perfect for this job